# Change Outlook archive location

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2003

I am working on a script to move user's Outlook (we run 2003, 2007, and 2010) archive's to a central location on our servers.  What I'm looking for is a way to move the archive to the server, then change the Outlook settings so that it auto-archive's to that remote location.

Preferably this would be done with no interaction from the user, and without installing third-party applications.  Does such a solution exist?

Note: I'm looking to automate this using either a batch script or a Visual Basic program.

Comment: Are you using Exchange server?

Comment: Yes, we are also running a mixed environment of 32-bit and 64-bit clients as well.

Comment: Having PST files on a network location is a really bad idea.

Comment: Exchange 2010 can manage this through Persoanl Archives

Comment: @DaveM Sorry, we're running Exchange 2007.  Didn't mention that.